# Unable to connect to HSQLDB after running a couple of tests (which worked before)

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, hsqldb

Hi I am working with Spring, Hibernate 3 and JPA and I have configured my JUnit Tests to connect to a HSQLDB (In Memory) instead of the MySQL database that I use for my application. This worked fine for some time until recently, just out of the blue I couldn't connect to the HSQLDB Heres the stack trace and my .xml and .properties configuration files

```
11:06:41,979         INFO Dialect:206 - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
11:06:41,986         INFO JdbcSupportLoader:70 - Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
11:06:41,987         INFO TransactionFactoryFactory:62 - Transaction strategy: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringTransactionFactory
11:06:41,988         INFO TransactionManagerLookupFactory:80 - No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
11:06:41,988         INFO SettingsFactory:169 - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
11:06:41,988         INFO SettingsFactory:173 - Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
11:06:41,989         INFO SettingsFactory:188 - Scrollable result sets: disabled
11:06:41,990         INFO SettingsFactory:196 - JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): disabled
11:06:41,990         INFO SettingsFactory:204 - Connection release mode: auto
11:06:41,991         INFO SettingsFactory:231 - Default batch fetch size: 1
11:06:41,991         INFO SettingsFactory:235 - Generate SQL with comments: disabled
11:06:41,991         INFO SettingsFactory:239 - Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
11:06:41,991         INFO SettingsFactory:243 - Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
11:06:41,992         INFO SettingsFactory:410 - Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
11:06:41,994         INFO ASTQueryTranslatorFactory:47 - Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
11:06:41,994         INFO SettingsFactory:251 - Query language substitutions: {}
11:06:41,994         INFO SettingsFactory:256 - JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
11:06:41,994         INFO SettingsFactory:261 - Second-level cache: enabled
11:06:41,994         INFO SettingsFactory:265 - Query cache: disabled
11:06:41,995         INFO SettingsFactory:395 - Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.NoCachingRegionFactory
11:06:41,995         INFO SettingsFactory:275 - Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
11:06:41,995         INFO SettingsFactory:284 - Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
11:06:42,000         INFO SettingsFactory:304 - Echoing all SQL to stdout
11:06:42,001         INFO SettingsFactory:313 - Statistics: disabled
11:06:42,001         INFO SettingsFactory:317 - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
11:06:42,001         INFO SettingsFactory:332 - Default entity-mode: pojo
11:06:42,002         INFO SettingsFactory:336 - Named query checking : enabled
11:06:42,002         INFO SettingsFactory:340 - Check Nullability in Core (should be disabled when Bean Validation is on): enabled
11:06:42,063         INFO SessionFactoryImpl:199 - building session factory
11:06:42,315         INFO SessionFactoryObjectFactory:105 - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
11:06:42,323         INFO SchemaExport:226 - Running hbm2ddl schema export
11:06:42,325         INFO SchemaExport:251 - exporting generated schema to database
11:07:11,327         WARN BasicResourcePool:1224 - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@1d4eeb5 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30).
11:07:11,327         WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:100 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
11:07:11,328        ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:101 - Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
11:07:11,329        ERROR SchemaExport:274 - schema export unsuccessful
java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:104)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:264)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(PoolBackedDataSource.java:94)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource.getConnection(ComboPooledDataSource.java:521)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1385)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:954)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:551)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:972)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:208)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:260)
```

Comment: More with the configuration files:

Comment: test-configuration.properties
       jdbc.driver.className=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
    jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:unit-testing-jpa
    jdbc.username=root
       jdbc.password=root
       jdbc.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect

Comment: are closing the connections properly? post the database connection part of the code and configuration files.

Comment: Hibernate takes care of the database, I posted everything

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with using HSQLDB as in memory database. Especially I use `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool` too. It turned out that the JAR `hsqldb.jar` was not on the class path. After adding it everything works fine.